# How to use gulp-rev with file.revHash?

Tags: gulp, gulp-rev

from gulp-rev @ link : https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev
I have wrote a task to simple

```
gulp.task('build-app', function () {
   return gulp
        .src([gulpConfig.clientApp + '*.js'])
        .pipe($.rev())
// i want to get the updated hash, which I will use to replace the string in some place

}
```

Any idea how to acheive it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [gulp-filenames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filenames) to store the new/hashed filename. I haven't done this with gulp-rev but I have with [gulp-freeze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-freeze)

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src('./js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(freeze())
        .pipe(filenames('some-string'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Then in another task you can get that hashed filename with:

```
filenames.get('some-string');
```

Comment: what is the out put of freeze () ? its not on site documentation

Comment: yeah it is: "This gulpfile creates a file named like app.min_0187d9d019510c4e1492acad3015fda0.js from your app.min.js"